# How to write a Ternaray conditional operator for 3 conditions in Swift code

Tags: ios, swift5

How can this be done for 3 conditions,

```
 if isFirstBool {
  print ("Hello")
    } else if isSecondBool {
    print ("World")
  } else {
      print ("Hello World")
  }
```

Comment: isFirstBool  ?  print ("Hello") : (isSecondBool ?  print ("World") :  print ("Hello World"))

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in following way.

```
let msg = isFirstBool ? "Hello" : (isSecondBool ? "World" : "Hello World")
print(msg)
```

Comment: You don't need the brackets.

Comment: I've just added for the code clarity. but compiler doesn't complain about it.